# Firebase 'value' event handler is called first with null value and then with the actual value

Tags: firebase

I am using `firebase-queue` in a mobile app to offload some work to a server. I send tasks to the firebase queue with a request and start to listen to 'value' events at `responses/<request-id>` to get the response for the task. The firebase queue worker will receive the task, process it and set the results at `responses/<request-id>`.

I am observing that the `value` event handler is called twice, initially with a null value and then will the actual response. I have this sample code which can be used to simulate the behavior

**client.js**

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

var ref = new Firebase('https://propertyfindercp.firebaseio.com');

ref.child('responses/<request-id>').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Value event ', snapshot.val());
});
```

**worker.js**

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

var ref = new Firebase('https://propertyfindercp.firebaseio.com');
ref.child('responses/<request-id>').set({data: 123});
```

Just replace the `<request-id>` in both the files to some same random value and run the `client.js` file by using `node client.js` and then the `worker.js` by using `node worker.js`

I observe the following output on the client console

```
Value event  null
Value event  { data: 123 }
```

I was expecting to see only the second line. Why is the `value` event handler called with a `null` value also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the listener, there is no value at location `responses/<request-id>`. So the Firebase client fires a `value` event with a `null` value.

Then when a value is written to `responses/<request-id>`, the `value` event fires again with the new value.

If you'd delete the value from `responses/<request-id>`, you'd get another `value` event with `null`.

Comment: @ FrankvanPuffelen I understand that when I delete the value from `responses/<request-id>`, I would get another `value` event with `null` value because I actually set a `null` at that location but it is a bit counter-intuitive that I receive a null value when I first attach a `value` event handler at a location. Actually, it kind of renders the `once` event handler useless in this case because it ends up getting called with `null` value and it is not called when the value is actually set. What is the purpose of calling the `value` event handler with `null` value when it is first attached? 1

Comment: Moreover, I don't even know if a `value` event handler is called with `null` value, is it because the value is deleted at that location so that I can handle it accordingly or is it just the initial call. So, I may end up with some more if-else logic in the code 2

Comment: I explained how the API works. Here's how you could make a "wait for value" listener, which is likely what you're trying to do: https://twitter.com/puf/status/719889323655634945

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the gist that explain how to add a "wait for value" listener. It is what I am trying to do. I guess my main concern was why was the `value` event handler called with `null` value but I think I understand now what that is the case. Because the `value` event is used to get both the current value and any value changes at a given location and when the event handler was initially attached, the value was `null` at that location as you wrote in the answer. Thanks again!